# Is RAM always volatile?

Tags: memory-hardware

I understand that computer memory in typical modern computing systems (such as the laptop I am asking this question from) is generally involatile but in some exceptions, such as RAM, the memory is indeed volatile.

Is RAM always volatile? Isn't there any "exceptional" kind of involatile RAM by humans somewhere?

Comment: It would be great if we had such a RAM that still has enough memory and operates fast :)

Comment: This is a question about computer technology, not about computer science. And it's too broad for Stack Exchange anyway. Start with the [Wikipedia article about RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) and search for “non-volatile”.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' but all I want to know is if RAM **must** be volatile or that in *theory* there could be non-volatile RAM. From your reference I understand that yes, there not only can be, but there is, as from the article `Non-volatile random-access memory`. If it's not a matter in computer science than okay, I understand if the question would be closed/migrated.

Comment: The question is: how do you define "RAM"? If you define the term "RAM" in such a way that it excludes non-volatile memory, then RAM is always volatile. If you define the term "RAM" in such a way that it includes both non-volatile and volatile memory, then RAM can be both non-volatile and volatile.

Answer (score 0):

Go 45 to 65 years back in time when RAM was “core memory” - tiny magnetic rings with wires threaded between them. Core memory was not volatile.